# scripts in rc.local block starting up system

Tags: bash, scripts

Encountered a weird problem, today I just upgraded Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10, and reboot the system. However, my computer cannot get into desktop, seems that blocked by my script in `/etc/rc.local`. The scripts like this:

```
sslocal -c /home/kinka/azure.conf
```

And commenting out the script, I can get into my Ubuntu normally.
Also, running the script in background also works too.

```
sslocal -c /home/kinka/azure.conf &
```

I don't know what leads to such a change?

Comment: Try including the full path to sslocal in your rc.local. Also, does running sslocal on the command line return you to a command prompt?

Comment: but why? sslocal did found by the shell, and I can saw it on the booting screen. It is running.

Comment: Because rc.local does not use your path. Or you may need to add  '&' at end of command in rc.local.

Comment: I mean sslocal without full path can work, but not running in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main reason is because by its nature it is sequential.

What you have to understand is that `/etc/rc.local` exists for compatibility with the old SysV init system for bringing up services, and SysV originally started out as sequential system way back in the good old days of AT&T Unix. As [chaos explains in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233475/85039):

> SysV executes the scripts in sequential order based on their number in the filename. Systemd doesn't. If dependencies are met, systemd runs the scripts immediately, without honoring the numbering of the script names.

Second reason is that `rc.local` in itself is a script ( noticed the `#!/bin/sh -e` line ?). The scripts by nature are sequential as well, so if one command haven't finished or haven't been put into background - the script will have to wait for program A to do its mumbo jumbo or fail entirely before anything else can happen. Besides, notice the comments at the top of the file:

```
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
```

So your `sslocal -c /home/kinka/azure.conf` simply holds the system hostage and doesn't let the script exit and complete system boot. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer. However, what confuses most is that the script works before ubuntu **17.04** but block booting into ubuntu **17.10**. Why came out such a break change? Maybe it's my fault not using it the right way.

Comment: The behavior should be consistent since rc.local is standard file, unless something changed either on your end ( most likely ) or on systemd end. I won't be making wild guess here.